# Как запустить проект Nuxt.js на centerOS VPS?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, веб-программирование, vue.js

### У меня очень большая проблема, т.к. я не разбираюсь в VPS и мне нужно выложить проект на nuxt.js.

### Вот что я сделал как только зашёл через PuTTy к себе на сервер:

1. yum -y update
2. yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
3. yum -y install screen
4. Установил Node.js, npm, git
5. Склонировал проект nuxt.js
6. Запустил проект путём (1 - npm run build, 2 - npm run start)
7. Проект запустился на localhost:3000

Хостинг привязан на мой домен, проверяю - и страница не запускается

### Что я делаю не так? Помогите пожалуйста, я вообще просто не знаю что делать...

Уже пересмотрел кучу видео/ статей/ просил помощью у помощников моего хостинга и всё в пустую.

### Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: `Проект запустился на localhost:3000`. `sudo netstat -ntl | grep 3000` в студию. Если команда не выполнится, поставьте netstat: `sudo yum install net-tools`. Так мы посмотрим открыт наружу этот порт или нет. А вообще, что хотите, на каком порте его открыть? 80?

Comment: Ну желательно на там, где запускается проект :)

Comment: Переформулирую: хотите чтобы проект открывался в браузере по типу `http://мой-сайт.ru/`?

Comment: Да, всё верно :)

Comment: Как вариант, в настройках указать порт 80. Но тогда `npm run start` потребуется выполнять от суперпользователя (`sudo ...`), так как все порты до 1024 требуют этого. Вариант получше: nginx как реверс-прокси. Он будет перенаправлять трафик с 80 порта (протокол HTTP) на 3000 (там ваш сервер). В последствии можно будет сделать виртуальные хосты через nginx. Что выбираете?

Comment: Вообще покажите `sudo netstat -ntl | grep 3000` после того как запустите  `node run start`

Comment: Проект доступен по адресу http://site.com:3000 ? Если да, то тебе нужно через nginx перенаправить трафик с 80 порта на 3000

Comment: Нгинкс, прокси пасс. И через системд запускалку нюкста..

Comment: пункты 5,6,7 делаются только на компе разработчика. на сервер надо делать нормальный деплой

Answer (score 0):

Вы запустили проект на localhost. Извне он доступен не будет. Либо запустите свой проект на внешнем интерфейсе, либо сделайте ssh-туннель:
ssh -L 3000:localhost:3000 IP_АДРЕС_СЕРВЕРА
После этого в браузере набрать: 127.0.0.1:3000

Comment: Не факт что порт не открыт наружу. И тоннель организовывать под это дело бессмысленно и беспощадно: тоннель по своей природе - временное решение, он с легкостью может перестать быть. Пользователи интернета не откроют этот сайт. Чтобы было стабильно, следует использовать реверс-прокси. Я предпочитаю nginx

Comment: А что же мне делать? Можете дать инструкцию поэтапно, пожалуйста

Comment: Первый этап - посмотреть, как слушается 3000 порт. `sudo netstat -ntl | grep 3000` покажет это. Если `0.0.0.0` - порт доступен наружу. Это утверждение надо еще проверить: возможно, блокирует файрвол, как на сервере, так и у вас на машине. Это уже второй этап